# How to get the uri of ResourceDictionary.XAML in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

if you want to change the ResourceDictionary in code, you have to write a long path, like `new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/System/Language/Window1_EN.xaml", UriKind.Absolute)`. 
Is there any way I can use by using the file name (Window11_EN.xaml) to get its Path of Project (/System/Language) ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to have property that could store your file path

```
public string xmlfilepath{get;set;}
```

now, all you have to do is to get application base directory, and concatenate with your path,
as an example i have created:

```
 static string path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        static string debug = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        static string bin = Path.GetDirectoryName(debug);
        static string projectfolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(bin);
        public string xamlFilepath = projectfolder + "\\System\\Language\\Window1_EN.xaml";
```

or if it is in the bin/debug try using this one

```
xmlfilepath= System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "your folder name and file name path will come here";
```

Comment: It may not be that, because the directory in this Solution is compile into a exe file. It have no directory in Debug directory.

Comment: that is why i have given first suggestion to move into your project folder and then choose your desired folder from your prject folder. try it.

Comment: I don't want to move the folder into Debug directory. I want all the resources in a dll file.

Comment: SinghIf you public your app, the code you give will fail. because there are no Bin/Debug directory in exe.

Answer (score 0):

That's my problem. I have a Window1_EN.xaml resourcedictionary file, like the following picture shows. we can use uri syntax to get the file according to its directory in Solution Explorer. we don't need to copy the folder into Bin/Debug directory. But it need to write it manually. Is the anyway I can code it?

[image]